# Possible arguments in pyton3 printed in terminal

Tags: python-3.x

How to print all possible assigns for arguments in python to the terminal?
For instance, how to find what can I use for [markers](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html) using terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python libraries generally have something called docstrings which could include usage help, methods, parameters, examples, etc. These documentation can be accessed via the built-in function `help()` in Python. `help()` will basically list out all the help contents on the screen.

In your case, you might not want all the unnecessary information to be displayed on the screen. So, you can just get the documentation string using the `__doc__` property and then extract the required information, in this case only the marker parameters. Here's a little snippet of code which you can use to print out the parameters to the user:

```
import matplotlib.markers

...

def print_markers():
    table_line_counter = 0
    docstring_list = matplotlib.markers.__doc__.split('\n')

    for line in docstring_list:
        if line.startswith('==='):
            table_line_counter += 1

        if table_line_counter > 0:
            print(line)

        if table_line_counter == 3:
            return

...

# Call this function whenever you want to display
# the table of parameter options

print_markers()
```

Here, the `matplotlib.markers.__doc__` property returns a string. You can use the `split()` method in conjunction to it in order to get a list of strings separated by newline characters. You can then use a counter to check when the table content starts & ends and print all the content between between that range.